# How to get EmbeddedResource from different assembly?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I have an Assembly, MainLib.dll, with a resource that I retrieve with:

```
string resourcePath = String.Format("MainLib.{0}", "EmbeddedResource.txt");
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream inputStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePath);
```

This works fine.  Now I need to move EmbeddedResource.txt to it's own lib, ResourceLib.dll.

How do I retrieve it now from ResourceLib.dll and use it in MainLib.dll now that it is in a separate dll?

Comment: You want to `move embedded resource to other assembly` or `load resource from other than executing assembly`?

Comment: I want to retrieve it from ResourceLib, and use it in MainLib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get `ResourceLib` assembly to get its embedded resource -

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ClassNameInThatAssembly));
```

OR

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("ResourceLib");
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was trying to use Assembly.LoadFrom("ResourceLib") but I was including .dll which is not needed.